# Will incremental backup notify if a previous full/incremental backup didn't succeed?

Tags: backup

I am not sure what tool under Ubuntu to use for back up yet.

If the last full or incremental backup finished without reporting any problem but there actually was a problem, can some tool report its problem and fix it during the next incremental backup? Or all/most tools will do incremental backup which will be meaningless because it is based on an failed full or incremental backup? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In general: when a synch fails the next time it should do a synch based on the previous successful synch or it should make a copy of the whole file. But this depends on the actual command and the software used.

Use the "rsync" command and create your own solution. That way you know what it does, you can create exceptions and can put in safeguards (like sending mails). And you learn something about your machine.

"rsync" is just a command like any other. Example:

```
rsync [options] [arguments] | mail -s "subject" e@mail.com
```

Figure out what [options](http://www.tecmint.com/rsync-local-remote-file-synchronization-commands/) and [arguments](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/rsync-command-examples/) you [want](https://rsync.samba.org/examples.html) to use. Put it into a script and call the script from /etc/crontab.